# Flink checkpoints are very slow after upgrading from Flink 1.13.1 to Flink 1.14.3

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am experiencing extremely slow checkpoints after upgrading flink version from 1.13.1 to 1.14.3. The checkpointing is slow because of the sink/source.
Example
[image]

This source is a kafka topic that have some messages inside and still, it might take up to minutes to be checkpointed.

I am using incremental checkpoints, unaligned checkpoints are not enabled. Configurations are the default ones, and this source was checkpointed for milliseconds with flink 1.13.1 and now it times out(the timeout is 3 minutes) for every second chechpoint.

[image]

[FlinkKafkaConsumer](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer.html)/[Producer](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer.html) are used which are deprecated.

Comment: Can you clarify if you use KafkaSource or old FlinkKafkaConsumer. Your OP is ambiguous in that regard.

Comment: I assume it's FlinkKafkaConsumer that's deprecated since they are saying that it's not the new one. I am facing the same issue with that one, and I don't use a Kafka sink.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am using FlinkKafkaProducer/FlinkKafkaConsumer which are deprecated. I will upgrade and check. Thanks!

Comment: But why using the deprecated consumer/producer would have such dramatic effect on checkpoint speed?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if it's an issue with the new KafkaSource (which received updates to 1.14) or the old KafkaConsumer which didn't. So this looks like an issue (=bug) with legacy sources. I'd either file a bug ticket in https://issues.apache.org/jira/ or seek help on user@flink.apache.org. Stackoverflow is the wrong venue to look into bugs.

Comment: Sorry @MonikaX, but without more information it's impossible to help you. I would suggest reaching out to user@filnk.apache.org (and ping me and Arvid here what's the topic of the mail, so that we can find your message), as it would most likely require asking quite a bit of back and forth questions. When you will be posting your question, please include screenshots from 1.13.x and 1.14.x of the:
1. Job graph from the Web UI, that show backpressure/busy stats.
2. Detailed checkpoint stats of all tasks and subtasks, including alignment time, start delay, end to end time, etc.

Comment: @PiotrNowojski I will reach out as suggested and provide the required info. Thank you!

Comment: @MonikaX, please also attach JobManager logs. As your first screenshots suggests (long end to end checkpoint time for the source task, with all other times like sync, async, alignment time, start delay, being very low) there is some problem on the JobManager that makes it unresponsive. Either some long GC pauses or maybe it's io thread pool is overloaded.

Comment: How is this going? Is there a bug ticket?

Comment: @RaúlGarcía, here is the bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27481